# Why is this MongoDB ObjectID infinite in Google spreadsheet?

Tags: mongodb, google-sheets, exponentiation, objectid

Type the MongoDB ObjectID `52489e882967060200000283` into a cell in a Google spreadsheet and it's clobbered by `∞`.  What gives?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See that small `e` in the middle? Google Sheets is treating this as a number in exponent form. i.e.

```
52489 x 10^882967060200000283
```

Probably less than the number of subatomic particles in the known universe, but close enough to infinity not to matter.

**Edit:** Actually, the number of atoms in the known universe is estimated to be about 1 x 10^82, so this is *slightly* larger...

Comment: Well, it's still less than .000000000000000000000000000000000000001% of infinity, but +1 anyway.

Comment: And the string won't be coerced into `∞` if you precede it with a single quotation mark, or pre-format the cell(s) as "Plain Text".

Answer (score 1):

I remember that mongo objectID is in hexadecimal. So the e actually means 14. But google mistakenly treat it as a exponential.

Source: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/ObjectId/

Comment: Why did you say this?